# C# - Client for WCF REST service JSON

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, rest

I try to create a simple client for WCF REST service' that I found
[here.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/571813/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Creating-WCF-REST-Services)

I Added the service reference and I wrote this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    string serviceURL =
            string.Format("http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksNames");
    byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    DataContractJsonSerializer obj =
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(finalProject_ClientX.ServiceReference3.Book));
    finalProject_ClientX.ServiceReference3.Book book = obj.ReadObject(stream) as finalProject_ClientX.ServiceReference3.Book;
    MessageBox.Show("book ID : " + book.BookName);

}
```

When I run the code (press the button) I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
>
> Additional information: The type
>   'finalProject_ClientX.ServiceReference3.Book' cannot be serialized to
>   JSON because its IsReference setting is 'True'. The JSON format does
>   not support references because there is no standardized format for
>   representing references. To enable serialization, disable the
>   IsReference setting on the type or an appropriate parent class of the
>   type.

When I run "http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksNames" in the browser I got the books:

> "["MVC Music Store - Tutorial -
>   v3.0","Pro.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Framework","Application Architecture Guide
>   v2","Gang of Four Design Patterns","CS4 Pocket Reference"]"

What is the problem?

Comment: Do you own the service?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot where? In the client?

Comment: As in, do you own the definition of the service you are referencing? Can you change its contracts?

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I don't  understand

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Entity framework include the property `IsReference = true` when it add the attribute DataContract.

So , I would recommend you to include the [JSON.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) nuget package in your project.
Then modify you code to something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient proxy = new WebClient();
    string serviceURL =
            string.Format("http://localhost:53215/IBookService.svc/GetBooksNames");
    byte[] data = proxy.DownloadData(serviceURL);

    var jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    IList<string> bookNames = JArray.Parse(jsonString).ToObject<IList<string>>();

    //Do something with the list
    //foreach (string bookName in bookNames)
    //{

    //}    
}
```

Comment: `IsReference` is false by default.

Comment: I tried to change it...  but I also get an error. "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
"